# Microsoft SQL Server : existing table new PK & index issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an old database that unfortunately a choice was made when it was designed that one of the largest tables, which contains photos (table called `Photos`) and has a PK of type `uniqueidentifier`. This table has 195k rows and obviously nearly 100% fragmentation. I would like to build a new PK on this table, but have some questions and considerations

**Data Background**

The row size of the table is not expected to grow beyond the bounds of (int). Additionally there are no FK relationships with the PK of the `Photos` table. As stated, there are 195k rows in the `Photos` table.  There is a potential consideration: there is a non-unique column in `Photos` called `Job_ID` which has FK relationship with the PK of another table called `DeliveryTicket`. The nature of that key is such that it's a an incrementing counter (int). There is a one->many relationship between the PK `Job_ID` in table `DeliveryTicket` and the FK `Job_ID` in table `Photos`.

My concerns stem from a perspective of fragmentation, and indexing, and my questions are:

1. How to add the new column `New_ID` to `Photos` with a PK constraint as non-null AND populate existing rows with a new incrementing index of type (int)?
2. Should I, and how do I, create a new clustered index on the FK value on the `Photos` table?  Note that it is expected by way of the program logic that most queries to the `Photos` table will be on the FK value `Job_ID`, but never on either the existing or any new PK of the `Photos` table. The fastest index for the table `Photos` would be on the FK relationship column `Job_ID`.
3. Is there a better approach to say somehow create a new PK that counts up from the lowest (non-unique on `Photos`) value of `Job_ID`, such that the default index (the PK) would be the fastest index?

Here is the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `Photos`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Photos]
(
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
    [Photo_Serial_Number] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Job_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Photo_Upload_Disposition_Type] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NET_Rating] [real] NULL,
    [Rating_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Image_Data] [varbinary](max) FILESTREAM  NOT NULL,
    [File_Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [File_Extension] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [Image_Comments] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_Photos] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)
);
```

I am in the exploratory phase. This is a production DB, and while it will be backed up and changes tested, as it has to happen during a maintenance windows, no such changes have yet been made.

Comment: How have you proved that this level of fragmentation is causing any problem that needs fixing? "nearly 100% fragmentation" is not in itself a problem. What actual performance issue do you have?

Comment: Instead of adding a `New_Id` column, why not use the existing `Photo_Serial_Number` `IDENTITY` column? I would create a composite clustered primary key constraint on `Job_ID` and `Photo_Serial_Number` to optimize queries by `Job_ID`.

Comment: the problems with performances are most likely to be due to the varbinary stuff or the comments which takes up some space, not the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER. 150k rows is not much, especially since i don't think that filestream stuff is stored on the page, it shouldn't take a lot of time to traverse the table. Which queries do you have problems is? a SELECT * will probably be slow whatever you do

Comment: I understand, and there are other tables where I'm not concerned about fragmentation.  This one takes performance hits when querying by Job_ID.  @DanGuzman I think the composite key you suggest may be a viable solution.  I'm obviously not terribly savvy here, I'm familiar with a composite key for uniqueness which isn't itself the issue here, however you appear to be suggesting that the corresponding clustered index on that key would improve performance for queries on *part* of the key (i,.e. the Job_ID).  Am I understanding that correctly?

Answer (score 1):

> This table has 195k rows and obviously nearly 100% fragmentation.

So what?  Do you have a measurable performance issue?  You could simply add a default of NEWSEQUENTIALID to generate sequential GUIDs to reduce fragmentation going forward.

Comment: Yes, there is a measurable performance issue and I appreciate your suggestion, which could mitigate the issue going forward, but not solve the issue with the extant rows.  The majority of queries are on the Job_ID column, which is not indexed (or unique on that table).  For instance, I just ran a query for all Job_ID's > 39000 (there are only 39786 Job_ID'), it took more than 10 minutes to execute.

Comment: Sounds like you need an index on Job_ID.  Foreign key columns should normally be indexed.  If you primarily access this table by Job_ID, then adding that as the leading column of your clustered index may be beneficial.